# What's the difference between Pentaho BI Platform Community Edition and Pentaho Kettle?

Tags: pentaho

Is it just that one is web based (BI Platform Community Edition) and the other is an application (Kettle). Can Kettle be access through a web browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BI Platform/Server is a web platform for performing data mining and running reports.
From the Pentaho community [website](http://community.pentaho.com/projects/bi_platform/):

`"...the Pentaho BI Server which functions as a web based report management system, application integration server and lightweight workflow engine (action sequences.)"`

While it can be used to create action sequences, it lacks the features of Kettle, which is a fully-fledged desktop ETL tool. Kettle provides none of the analysis or reporting functionality found in the BI server, and BI server lacks the ETL capabilities. They are two very different tools.

Comment: Not correct. Kettle is embedded in the BI Server, so can be used from within reports, or for running any of your ETL jobs.  There is also an integration specific server which is just kettle ( DI Server ) but this is EE only.

Comment: What do you mean by "can be used from within reports"? BI server can run jobs that were created in Kettle, yes, but I'm not aware of any editing features.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean byt a "specific server which is just kettle", what is "EE". Does this mean that it can be run as a web service like BI Server?

Comment: A report can use PDI as a data source. Plus as you say xactions can run jobs too.  Of course you can't edit from the BI Server, thats what spoon is for.  I can't imagine why you'd ever want to edit your solution on the server.  EE is enterprise edition.

Comment: Ah, silly me. The common mistake I make is to equate "using Kettle" to "using Spoon", so when I said that BI server lacks the capabilities of Kettle, I actually meant that it had no ability for creating or editing transformations.

Comment: ah I see, yes true. However I can't see why you'd want to edit your transformations/jobs in the BI server anyway.  If you really did need this functionality, i believe ( but not 100% ) that you can launch spoon using "java web start".  But again - I can't see why anyone would want this!